# Update content of div auto

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update a div's content automatically with this script:

```
function update() {
  $.get("authentication/notifications.php", function() {
    $(".notificationBox").html();
    window.setTimeout(update, 10000);
  });
}
```

But for some reason it's not working. Nothing happens on the page.

notifications.php has to get some data from the database. And I know it's getting it, cus on a normal update of the page it's showing up.

notificationsBox is inside of the notifications.php and is just a normal div in a foreach() loop.

My notifications.php looks like this:

```
<?$notifications = $db->notifications();

foreach($notifications as $notifications):?>
   <div class='notificationBox'><?=$notifications['pushCommentsContent'];?></div>
<?endforeach;?>
```

I want the DIV to be outputted on update, or to be added to the existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use load, it can do the sorting for you:

```
$('.notificationBox').load('authentication/notifications.php .notificationBox', function() {
  window.setTimeout(update, 10000);
});
```

Here it will search otifications.php for a element with class notificationBox and insert that into a element on your current page with the class notificationBox.

So it's important that the class of the element you want to update has the class :)

---

You are not inserting the contet you get, into anything :)

```
function update() {
  $.get("authentication/notifications.php", function(newdata) {
    $(".notificationBox").html(newdata);
    window.setTimeout(update, 10000);
  });
}
```

Comment: oh of couse. -.-' How would I do that? How do I define what 'newdata' has to be?

Comment: In the code i posted `newdata` is ALL of the returning html. You could easily sort it though, if you only need a specific set of contents. Is that what you want? :)

Comment: your authentication/notifications.php returns data that data will be captured in newdata

Comment: you dont have to define anything, newdata is what jquery has gotten from your get request, and you can pass it to your function as an arguemtn. read this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ 

so what it means is that, once you do the request, the first argument passed to the success function will be the data fetched

Comment: so, if the .get page is including some other html then the data output, it's updating this too?

Comment: It takes ALL html, so yes. Do you have a certain div or something with an ID/CLASS with the content you want? Then ill update with a sorting :)

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen I would like to an extra div class='notificationBox' when there's something new.

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen Marco, I can see that you're from Denmark, so am I - could we start a chat here on stackoverflow instead of spamming the comments? :-)

Comment: Sure.. just need to figure out how it works :P Im in room: Javascript

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen I have an content div '#infoBox'. where the notificationBox has to appear inside. Do I have to change .notificationBox to #infoBox, and keep the div .notificationBox as it is?

Answer (score 1):

> But for some reason it's not working. Nothing happens on the page.

That's because your code isn't doing DOM related. Perhaps you forgot to pass an argument to `html()`?

Comment: I see, please watch the other answer, I've commented another small question there. :)