# clear the div and reload a new audio content in that

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a database which contains the link to audio files. I am trying to play them one after the other using the HTML audio tag. Presently I am using PHP. My code -

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $r = mysql_query($sql);

       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
            $id = $row["audID"];                                                
            $audsq = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id ='$id'";            
            $resultaud = mysql_query($audsq);

            //Here I want to write a code to clear div="test"

            PlayAud(resultaud);
            sleep(2);   ///Not Sure             
        }
```

I am passing the link to aud file for the html to load and in

```
 <?php
      PlayAud($res) {
          $raud = mysql_fetch_array($res); ?>
      <div id="test">
      <audio> ...  </audio>
      </div>
 <?php }?>
```

Can some one tell me if I am doing it right ? also each clip is of 2 seconds hence I need to wait in the while loop for 2 seconds. If there is any other way can you suggest me?

Thank You

Comment: PHP is run server-side, before the browser sees anything. Adding `sleep(2)` in the PHP will just make the browser wait longer to see the entire page. You need a JavaScript solution.

Comment: First off - you should be executing a single query, read about [`JOIN`s in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) - you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` methods as they are being deprecated - [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) are good alternatives ... and you need to have a look into [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) and [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Ajax) as PHP runs on the server not on the client ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot clear a div from php. The reason is that php is running on the server, and the div is echoed out to the client, where it is unreachable by php.

A solution here could be to use Client side scripting (with JavaScript). You'd program a function, which replaces the audio tag or its contents, and it would probably be a good idea to implement some preloading-mechanism as well.

Greetings,
Jost

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT do what you want in PHP. You will have to use javascript. This question will help you:

[Update content of div auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063053/update-content-of-div-auto)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.... to clear to div you have to let the browser handle it, and you can do that through javascript.

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '';</script>";
//Then do what you needed to do
```